# Android Toolbar instead of action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I'm trying to use Toolbar instead of ActionBar. In Android 5.0.+ it works but in 4.4 the status bar is placed on top of the Toolbar.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"   
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"     
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:background="@color/actionbar_color"/>
```

Adding Toolbar in OnCreate():

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Full layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"   
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"     
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:background="@color/actionbar_color"/>

        <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dip"
            android:background="@color/actionbar_color" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/colors"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        style="@style/drawer_list"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

         <ListView 
             android:id="@+id/mainMenu"
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
             android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a frameLayout and in its height use `@dimen/statusBarHeight`. Then you can create an attrs.xml file for each version (normal, v19 and v21). Inside of each attrs.xml put  `<dimen name="statusBarHeight">25dp</dimen>`
Change 25dp to 0 in normal, 25 in v19 and 0 in v21. You can create attrs.xml for landscape mode too (values-land, values-land-v19, etc).

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/statusBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/statusBarHeight"
        android:background="?colorPrimaryDark"
        android:translationZ="4dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

Take a look this link: [Github](https://github.com/Dahnark/Material-Design-Navigation-Drawer)

Answer (score 0):

For Kitkat add:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Comment: Are you mean to add android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to toolbar?

Comment: In your main Layout where toolbar is.

Comment: Unfortunately not helped. I added the full Layout file to post

Comment: I had the same problem and it should work, have you tried to add android:fitsSystemWindows="true" in LinearLayout?

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial: http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/08/android-toolbar-example.html

Add in your XML layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#2196F3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In Java

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.azim.innovation.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.azim.innovation.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Colors**

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
```

**Styles**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

**Styles-v21**

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

**Dependency**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ThemeOverlay.NoActionBar theme. It dosen't add the Action Bar

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the theme in **styles.xml**.

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

If you are using a toolbar it should be NoActionBar in the theme.

Source: **[Android Toolbar Example](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-toolbar-example/)**.