# Android: How to customise App bar (action bar) like this?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appbarlayout

I need exactly like this, i saw some example to customise toolbar but could not design, how to use those gradients and all?

[image]

Comment: did you tried anything ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Toolbar instead of action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28532054/android-toolbar-instead-of-action-bar)

Comment: Atleast Research on that topic and if you did not find any solution, then ask Questions here, No efforts found in this Question

Comment: just create a drawable having gradient effect and set that drawable as background of toolbar

Comment: @VivekMishra Yes, I customised toolbar and created successfully but the things is the design means that black color shade and all, how to do that

Comment: @ShashwatGupta I am a newbie to android and of course I researched before asking here, I don't know how to create drawable. Help me

Comment: Create drawable : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13930644/5069323

Comment: there are tons of tutorials available for creating drawables. And if you are still unable to do that you can simply use an image like that as a background.

Comment: Do some RnD first, as there are lots of solutions on stackoverflow and on other site too.
if u researched it properly.

u can give gradients to it..

Comment: @Suhas please check answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `drawable` something like this `drawable`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient
    android:centerColor="@color/app_blue_color"
    android:endColor="@color/app_dark_blue_color"
    android:startColor="@color/app_dark_blue_color" />

<!--<corners-->
    <!--android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"-->
    <!--android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"-->
    <!--android:topLeftRadius="5dp"-->
    <!--android:topRightRadius="5dp" />-->

<stroke
    android:width="0.7dp"
    android:color="@color/app_blue_color" />
```

set this as the background of your customize toolbar

**create a ToolbarLayout**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/toolbarDrawable"
    android:gravity="top"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/RefreshButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/plus_icon"
            android:visibility="gone" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In your Activity include layout using

```
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_title" /> 

 // toolbar_tile is my toolbar layout name
```

Comment: @suhas choose color as per your need

Comment: Yeah I came to know how to create my own drawable file. Thank you @Shaifali and Shashwat